# for loop only iterates one time

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I don't know why this code isn't looping.

It just gives me the first result which is 17°C in 1 day. What about the rest of the values in the array?

```
const temperatures = [17, 21, 23];
const forcasting = function (arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
    let forCast = console.log(`${arr[i]}°C in ${i + 1} day.`);
    return forCast;
  }
};
forcasting(temperatures);
```

Comment: That is because you are returning out of the function on line 5 `return forCast;`. Also `i <= arr.length` is supposed to be `i < arr.length`

Comment: Are you trying to build a new array or print (or both)? `console.log()` returns undefined so it's pointless to assign that to anything. There's also a design flaw here, which is that the loop should go in the caller and the function should format only 1 item, maximizing reusability and flexibility. Function names are typically imperative verbs like `printForcast`, not present progressive (or whatever `forecasting` is).

Comment: @ggorlen, you're right, the problem was with the return statement which was out of the function, and i should be < arr.length.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning ‘forecast’ at the first iteration, it will cause the function to end (on any language and not only js), replace the return with print() and see the values.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with this code.
1st. It only loops once because you `return` in the first loop.

- `return` ends the code running inside that function and returns `forCast` making `forcasting` equal to the return from the `console.log()`
- just know returning in a loop will end it
  2nd. Also `for (let i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++)` will try to access index `3` when the last index is actually `2`. so it should be `for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)`

Answer (score 0):

you are using return before the loop ends. use this code:

```js
const temperatures = [17, 21, 23];

const forcasting = function (arr) {
  let forCast = null;
  for (let i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
     forCast = console.log(`${arr[i]}°C in ${i + 1} day.`);
  }
  return forCast;
};

forcasting(temperatures);
```